# How to check if a domain already exists in SWF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Is there a way to check if a domain name exists in SWF, instead of iterating the entire domain [list](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.html#listDomains%28com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.model.ListDomainsRequest%29)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are about to register that domain anyway in case, you could simply try to call [registerDomain()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.html#registerDomain%28com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.model.RegisterDomainRequest%29) and catch the [DomainAlreadyExistsException](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/model/DomainAlreadyExistsException.html):

> Returned if the specified domain already exists. You will get this
>   fault even if the existing domain is in deprecated status.

Obviously this has the side effect of actually registering the domain, if it doesn't exist yet ;)

Otherwise [describeDomain()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.html#describeDomain%28com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.model.DescribeDomainRequest%29) should allow a similar approach, insofar it will throw an [UnknownResourceException](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/model/UnknownResourceException.html) in case of a non existing domain:

> Returned when the named resource cannot be found with in the scope of
>   this operation (region or **domain**). This could happen if the named
>   resource was never created or is no longer available for this
>   operation. *[emphasis mine]*